# Invalidate session when closing the browser not working for other browsers apart from IE

Tags: javascript, session, onbeforeunload, invalidation

When I login to my application , after clicking login button my application will open in popup window(browser popup). I have written javascript code to log off from the application when I click on the close button(X) of popup window. I am able to log off from my application only on IE browser. But same code is NOT working on other browsers(Ex: Chrome,firefox...)

Here is my code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var valid = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e)
    {
      if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY<0)) // close button
      {
            LoggedOffWindow();
      }
    }; 

    //This will remove session
    function LoggedOffWindow()
    {
        var url = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/logoff.do';
        try {
            new Ajax.Request(url,
                {
                    method: 'get',
                    parameters: {},
                    onSuccess: function () {
                        ;
                    },
                    onFailure: function () {
                        ;
                    },
                    onException: function () {
                        ;
                    },
                    onComplete: function () {
                        ;
                    }
                });
        }
        catch (e) { alert(e.message); }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did the answer solved your problem?.  You can first verify if  LoggedOffWindow() is even being called at other browsers. Put alert in the first line of this function. If the alert does not show up that means problem is not with LoggedOffWindow() function but the condition in which it is wrapped.

Comment: You are right... I put alert. That is not being called when I close the browser  even in IE and other browsers. How can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

window.event is for IE only.

Instead of this:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e)
    {
      if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY<0)) // close button
      {
            LoggedOffWindow();
      }
    };
```

Use this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e)
{
 e = window.event || e; 
 if ((e.clientX < 0) || (e.clientY < 0))
 {
       LoggedOffWindow();
 }
};
```

EDIT: 
Check this link for useful information:
http://www.martinrinehart.com/early-sites/mrwebsite_old/examples/cross_browser_mouse_events.html

Comment: whats the issue now ?.  The first problem was that your function was not even being called at other browsers. Can you debug your program ?. OR put a code snippet here in sanboxed environment (comment out the ajax call ) So we can see if all browsers are able to pass your (window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY<0) condition.

Comment: Hello Jawad...Thanks for your response.My function was calling eariler also.. But it was not working on Chrome and other browsers. Removed Ajax code and tested , No progress